# SQLAlchemy, Declarative, PostgreSQL: cannot create tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I created a number of classes I want to persist to the database. I would like to be able to run the app with a specific flag to take all those classes and create the corresponding tables in my db. To that end, I'm trying to import the classes and then call the `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` method. However, that doesn't work. At the same time, when I call that from the file with each of those actual classes, the tables are created.

How do I go about the task of creating those tables? Should I try to create them from a single file/script, or do I add that line to each of those classes?

Here is an example of my code:

1) Item.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<~ {} ~> name: {}".format(self.id, self.name)
```

2) main.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def main():
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    Base = declarative_base()
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://me:my_passl@localhost/my_first_database', echo=True)
    from Item import Item
    print(Item)
    print(Item.__table__)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

main()
```

Sorry for the weird order of imports, but I read somewhere that the order of importing your classes and the Base matters, so I tried to play about with it.

Comment: One of the things I have found is that if I say `import Item`, and then `Item.__base__.metadata.create_all(engine)` everything works. But it looks like a slightly dirty hack. I thought that Base would be the same every time I create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already created `Base` in `Item.py`, just import it in `main.py`:

If `main.py` and `Item.py` are on the same folder, then in `main.py`:

`from Item import Base, Item`

And remove all imports inside `main` function, so `main.py` will look like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from Item import Base, Item

def main():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://me:my_passl@localhost/my_first_database', echo=True)
    print(Item)
    print(Item.__table__)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

main()
```

Comment: And what if I have a number of such DAOs? Do I create the Base elsewhere and then import it in each of these classes?

Comment: Why don't you group them in one file..like `models.py` and have `Base` in this same file..?

Comment: It's a thought. Coming from Java, having several "public" classes in one file is not what comes into mind first :)

Comment: Wel...if you had to separate them into multiple files, then gather them in one folder called for example `DataAccessLayer` and make it as a package folder putting an `__init__.py` file...then inside this file put all the necessary import statement to make it easier for your to just import it in your main app file by simply `import DataAccessLayer as DB` for example

Comment: Finally I found this! This solves my problem thank you very much!